# Click not firing on position absolute image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm practicing using .animate and other visual tricks by making an interactive sunset. I have all images except for the mountain positioned absolutely. I am trying to make clicking the sun trigger the sunset. Instead, the sunset loading animation runs, but clicking results in no actions. I also tried making a div around the sun and clicking that instead. I could not find a solution for this on overstack.

I've loaded jquery and bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<div id="everything">
    <img id="sunset" src="sunset1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    <img id="sun" src="sun1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    <img id="mountains" src="mountains.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    <img id="space" src="space5compressed.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    display: none;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    background-color: black;
}
#sun {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}
#sunset {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: -2;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#mountains {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -100%;
}
#space {
    position: absolute;
    left: -80%;
    bottom: -70%;
    min-height: 250%;
    min-width: 250%;
    max-height: 250%;
    max-width: 250%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.0;
    /* Spinning space effect*/
    -webkit-animation:spin 80s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 80s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 80s linear infinite;
}

    /* More spinning space effect*/
    @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

#everything {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").fadeIn(8000);

$("#sun").fadeIn(8000);

$( "#mountains" ).delay( 2000 ).animate({
    marginTop: "-25%",
}, 6000 );

$("#sun").on("click", function(){

    $( "#sun" ).animate({
        marginBottom: "-300px",
    }, 8000, "linear" );

    $( "#sunset, #sun" ).delay( 10000 ).animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
    }, 5000 );

    $( "#space" ).delay( 14000 ).animate({
        opacity: 4.0,
    }, 20000 );

});

});
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/0wwapsLw/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the solution. V31 hit upon the problem, although I'm still not quite sure why this works. Perhaps it doesn't matter that the mountains are a higher z-index because it was position relative and all I had to do was move space which is a higher z-index above sun in the HTML document. If anyone would like to expand on the explanation please do, but here's a working solution that keeps the click on the sun and the sun behind the mountains.

```
<div id="everything">
  <img id="sunset" src="sunset1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
  <img id="space" src="space5compressed.jpg" alt="">
  <img id="sun" src="sun1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
  <img id="mountains" src="mountains.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put z-index of #sun as 999 as other elements are at the same position overlapping it (as it is positioned absolute)

So your class should look like:

```
#sun {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
}
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#sun',function(){
    $('#sun').css('z-index',-1);
    $( "#sun" ).animate({
        marginBottom: "-300px",
    }, 8000, "linear" );

    $( "#sunset, #sun" ).delay( 10000 ).animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
    }, 5000 );

    $( "#space" ).delay( 14000 ).animate({
        opacity: 4.0,
    }, 20000 );

});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wwapsLw/5/)

Comment: The sun needs to fall behind the mountains, so this will not work.

Comment: @Goose: Updated the answer and fiddle, now the sun is falling behind the mountains...as Now handled z-index after click event

Comment: I posted an answer to my own question that's a little dryer, but I still don't understand why it works. You seem to understand z-index better than me. Why does order in the HTML document affect z-index. Isn't z-index absolute?

Comment: @Goose z-index is to work on layers. Since you putting it as -1 it will below other elements, and click wont happen as other elements are above it. Now what I had done was increased the z-index so that it is above layer with respect to other elements. The click happens and soon after the click I changed the z-index to -1 so that it again falls below the other elements. Hope this answer is convincing, if yes do mark the above as your answer then

Comment: Problem is the sun should be partly sitting behind the mountain before the click has happened. I still don't understand why moving space above sun in the document cleared it to be clicked? Is there a difference between relative and absolute in regard to z-index?

Comment: have a look at this article http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 0):

You used `body` instead of `'body'` in the script. It works now:

```
$('body').on("click", function(){

    $( "#sun" ).animate({
        marginBottom: "-300px",
    }, 8000, "linear" );

    $( "#sunset, #sun" ).delay( 10000 ).animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
    }, 5000 );

    $( "#space" ).delay( 14000 ).animate({
        opacity: 4.0,
    }, 20000 );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0wwapsLw/2/

Comment: Sorry, my jsFiddle was suppose to say ('#sun'), like my questions does. I was making sure click was working on the body, which it does. My code does not work on ('#sun').